# How does a very intricate Criteria API logic gets tested?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, criteria, criteria-api

I have built a very intricate 100+ lines of code of queries and joins and predicates that are added if some conditions are met and so on.

In short, I have to test all of this now and I have created mocks upon mocks upon mocks hoping Mockito is the way but this doesn't seem to be right.

I just wanted to know if there is other way to unit test the method in which I am creating this very elaborate logic?

Comment: I don't think that mocking is the correct way - with mocking you can only verify that your API works correctly if the database behaves the way you encode in the mocks. IMHO this can only be tested through integration tests with a real database.

Comment: Try using h2 for an in-memory database. That will already test against an actual database. Your code should then work against the real database as well, assuming that your JPA implementation doesn't do too weird things.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up mocking everything for this type of testing but also added some integration tests in order to properly check the functionality.